# Is the User Information List deprecated in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: 2010, user-profile-service, user-information-list

Is the User Information List deprecated in SharePoint 2010? I have been advised that it is, and that it can no longer be easily synched with AD.

It has been suggested that if I need this sort of user data for a data view, I should access the User Profile Service directly. However, short of using [a certain third party component](http://www.aconcaguait.com/sp2010upp.php), I cannot find any reference to doing so.

So is using the User Information List still a recomended practice, or is there a better way of getting the same data?

Answer (score 4):

The User Information List is alive and kicking in 2010. Whether using it makes any sense in your case would depend on what you mean by "this sort of user data".